# How to predict the outcomes form GEE regression across period of time

Tags: regression, predictive-models, generalized-estimating-equations

The recent paper by Liu et al. 2023 (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/ajh.26998) describes a single-arm study on crovalimab.
In the maintenance phase (weeks 5 to 25) patients were receiving the treatment and were evaluated every 4 weeks. The authors report the mean proportion of patients with hemolysis control of 78.7 [95%CI: 67.8–86.6], which was assessed using generalized estimating equation (GEE) model from week 5 through week 25.

I would like to conduct a similar analysis on my data of 100 patients (encoded as SUBJID), of whom each patient is evaluated weekly for the response. In particular, I would like to predict the mean probability of the response between weeks 10 and 30 using the following GEE model (gee library).

`res <- gee(RESPONSE ~ WEEK_NUMBER, id = SUBJID, data = MYDATA, family = binomial, corstr = "AR=M)`

The code works and now the question is how I can predict the mean proportion of responders from week 10 through 30 from *res*?

Comment: What is the question? Does the given code work? Please specify.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately it seems to me nothing more than a program problem which is off topic here. But I am not hasting to vtc; would wait for others to look into the post. Anyways, welcome to CV.